# Can't get response of GET request Axios

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, axios

I'm calling a GET Request from OpenWeather APIs like below:

```
const config = {
            headers: {
              accept: 'application/json',
            },
            data: {},
          };
        const url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
        Axios.get(url, config).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((e) => {
            Alert.alert('error', `${e}`);
            });
```

but `.then()` doesnt get called and after about 15 seconds  it throw an exception and `catch` alert is shown (saying `Network Error` while other API calls are working so network error is not really the problem).

the url is working in browsers but Axios can't make that call. 
anyone has any idea whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're requiring your NPM package at the top:

For Node/React:

```html
const axios = require('axios');

import axios from 'axios';
```

The code you provided worked for me. I simply installed axios, imported it, and lowercased "axios" in your example and I got a response from the weather service.

I got the following JSON data response (with some other stuff):

```html
 data:
   { cod: '200',
     message: 0.0036,
     cnt: 40,
     list:
      [ [Object],
        ...
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     city:
      { id: 524901, name: 'Moscow', coord: [Object], country: 'none' } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `async/await`.  It makes your code way easier to read and avoids callback hell.

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
   data: {},
  };

  const url = 'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';

  const response = await axios.get(url, config);
  console.log(response);
}
```